# internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:905 throw err; Error: Cannot find module '/opt/render/project/src/index.js'

Tags: node.js, express, render

My node project works in the local host perfectly but while deploying to render.com it's giving me the error. I don't understand why errors are coming. kindly help me with this.

plz, check the below error.

https://dashboard.render.com/web/srv-cijtv2mnqql0l1u99qvg/deploys/dep-cilnpsh5rnuvtgpq8nvg?mode=maximize

help me with this. I have spent a lot of time on this but not get any solution.